# 'Operation' object has no attribute '_id_value'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, loss-function

The `agent` and `prior` are two pre-trianed Keras functional models initialized from the stored graph and weights.

Then I define a loss function like this:

```
agent_logits = K.cast(K.max(agent_output, axis = 2), dtype = tf.float32)
prior_logits = K.cast(K.min(prior_output, axis = 2), dtype = tf.float32)

p_a_prior = K.sum(K.log(prior_logits), axis = 1)
p_a_agent = K.sum(K.log(agent_logits), axis = 1)

loss = K.mean(K.square(p_a_agent - p_a_prior))
```

Then I try to calculate the gradient:

```
grads = tf.gradients(loss, agent.trainable_weights)
```

I got this error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-435dabc8f049> in <module>()
     40 #   return grad, tf.negative(grad)
     41 
---> 42 grads = tf.gradients(loss, agent.trainable_weights)
     43 # grads = _compute_gradients(loss, agent.trainable_weights)
     44 print('[agent.inputs] = ', agent.inputs)

~/anaconda3/envs/hw3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py in gradients(ys, xs, grad_ys, name, colocate_gradients_with_ops, gate_gradients, aggregation_method, stop_gradients)
    488     pending_count, loop_state = _PendingCount(ops.get_default_graph(), to_ops,
    489                                               from_ops,
--> 490                                               colocate_gradients_with_ops)
    491 
    492     # Iterate over the collected ops.

~/anaconda3/envs/hw3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py in _PendingCount(graph, to_ops, from_ops, colocate_gradients_with_ops)
    169   for op in to_ops:
    170     reached_ops[op._id] = True
--> 171   _MarkReachedOps(from_ops, reached_ops)
    172 
    173   # Mark between ops.

~/anaconda3/envs/hw3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gradients_impl.py in _MarkReachedOps(from_ops, reached_ops)
    115   while queue:
    116     op = queue.popleft()
--> 117     if not reached_ops[op._id]:
    118       reached_ops[op._id] = True
    119       for output in op.outputs:

~/anaconda3/envs/hw3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in _id(self)
   1635   def _id(self):
   1636     """The unique integer id of this operation."""
-> 1637     return self._id_value
   1638 
   1639   @property

AttributeError: 'Operation' object has no attribute '_id_value'
```

Could anyone give me some suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the backend directly, I think you also need to use `gradients` method from the backend:

```
grads = K.gradients(...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now. When I posted this question, I got the agent_output and prior_output directly from calling agent.output and prior.output. Now I initialize a placeholder x for the input batch and get the output as agent_output = agent(x). wondering if they are the same or only the latter one is doable.

Comment: @beepretty I think they are the same. Did you get different results or any errors?

Comment: Just tested and the result is interesting. Using agent.output directly, and the session was fed as sess.run(grads, feed_dict = {agent.input: trainingBacth}),  the above error still exists. With a placeholder,  the gradients can be calculated but I'm still not sure if the weights haven't been truly updated.

Comment: @beepretty What session is stored in the `sess`? Did you create a new one? Or used the session implicitly created by Keras?

Comment: I use sess = tf.InteractiveSession(), and K.set_session(sess)

Comment: @beepretty Use this one and see if it works: `sess = K.get_session()`. Comment the line where you create the session using tensorflow.

Comment: Nope, it causes the same error T.T   it seems only work with a tensor placeholder

Comment: @beepretty Is there any reason to create sessions and run the graph using `run`? Instead, you can also use `my_function = K.function([input1, input2, ...], [output1, output2, ...])` and then use the created function like this: `out1, out2, ... = my_function([in1, in2, ...])`. Does it work for you?

Comment: I actually haven't used K.function() before, I'll try it in a little bit and come back to you. Really appreciate!

Comment: I refer several examples of K.function() and I understand that it always returns the output of a certain layer or the final output of the whole network. Instead, I try to use sess.run() to calculate the gradient w.r.t the trainable_variables of a given model. It's not obvious for me how to use it regarding my intention. Maybe I'm not right, welcome to correct.

Comment: @beepretty Like this: `my_func = K.function([the_inputs_of_your_model_or_function], [grads])`. And then: `grads_values = my_func([the_input_matrices])`. It is very similar to `Model`.